# Having trouble with php stored procedure mysql insert not working at all

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm having some trouble with php of not able to get the insert stored procedure mysql  with auto increment to work. Please do not mark duplicate.

```
//connect to database
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "buildings", "3306");

//Having trouble with insert stored procedure in which i've never done that part before and also, I'm not sure
//if the mysql_insert_id()) would work because it is auto increment

$Firstname = "Aaron";
$Lastname = "johnson";
$Password = "323";
$EmailAddress = "aaron@gmail.com";
$Salt = "23";
$RoleID = "1";

// tried passing the parameters and it still didn't work.

$sql = $connection->multi_query( "CALL registerusers(@new_id,$Firstname,$Lastname,$Password,$EmailAddress,$Salt,$RoleID);SELECT @new_id" ); 

echo "new record has id:" . mysqli_insert_id($connection);
```

Here's [the link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pkw2v71o0w8etv/create%20table%20users.txt?dl=0) for create table users in mysql.

Here's [the link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ofwmlgy5e89sxkl/registerusers.txt?dl=0) for stored procedure insert stored procedure in mysql

Here's the result of the php message that says "new record has id:0"

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use `multi_query`. It's a severe security risk and has no place being used in public-facing code.

Comment: I've never done any php stored procedure before and I'm new. I just want to know how to get the insert stored procedure to work in php.

Comment: This user registration code is woefully antiquated and shouldn't be used. You're better off scrapping it and starting again with something reasonable. MySQL does not have the tools necessary to implement secure password hashing.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.